# Biased of multi-step Q Learning for tabular case

Tags: q-learning

This is comes from cs2852023Fall, hw3.
I'm learning RL by myself and I cann't find answers related to this question.
The resource could be found in
https://rail.eecs.berkeley.edu/deeprlcourse/.

### Backgorund

Consider the N-step variant of Q-learning described.

\begin{align}
y_{i,j} \gets (\sum_{t'=t}^{t+N-1 }\gamma^{t'-t}r_{j,t'} + \gamma^N \max_{a_{j, t+N}}Q_{\phi_{k}}(s_{j,t+N}, a_{j,t+N}) (1)\\
\phi_{k+1} \gets \arg\min_{\phi\in\Phi}\sum_{j,t}(y_{j,t} - Q_{\phi}(s_{j,t}, a_{j,t}))^2 (2)
\end{align}
In these equations, $j$ indicates an index in the replay buffer of trajectories $_{k}$.  We first roll out a batch of B
trajectories to update  $_{k}$ and compute the target values in (1). We then fit $Q_{\phi_{k+1}}$ to these target values with (2). After estimating $Q_{\phi_{k+1}}$, we can then update the policy through an argmax:
$$
\pi_{k+1}(a_t | s_t) \gets 
\begin{cases}
  & 1\text{ if } a_{t} = \arg\max_{a_{t}}Q_{\phi_{k+1}}(s_{t}, a_{t})\\
  & 0\text { otherwise }
\end{cases}(3)
$$

We repeat the steps in eqs.(1) to (3) K times to improve the policy. In this question, you will analyze some properties of the algoriyhm, which is summarized in Algorithm 1.

## Question

At each iteraction of the algorithm above after update from eq.(2), $Q_{\phi_{k}}$ can be viewed as an estimate of the true optimal $Q^\star$. Consider the following statements:

**I.** $Q_{\phi_{k+1}}$ is an unbiased estimate of the $Q$ function of the last policy, $Q^{\pi_{k}}.$

**II.** As $k\to\infty$ for some fixed $B$ (replay_buffer), $Q^{\pi_{k}}$ is an unbiased estimate of $Q^{\star}$, i.e., $\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[Q_{\phi_{k}}(s,q) - Q^{\star}(s,a)] = 0$

**III.** In the limit of infinite iterations and data we recover the optmimal $Q^{\star}$, i.e.,  $\lim_{k,B\to\infty}\mathbb{E}[||Q_{\phi_{k}} - Q^{\star}||] = 0$

We make the additional assumptions:

- The state and action spaces are finite.
- Every batch contains at least one experience for each action taken in each state.
- In the tabular setting, $Q_{\phi_{k}}$ can express any function, i.e., ${Q_{\phi_{k}}:\phi\in\Phi}=\mathbb{R}^{S \times A}$

When updating the buffer $_{k}$ with $B$, we say:

- When learning on-policy, $_{k}$ is set to contain only the set of $B$ new rollouts of $\pi$ (so $|_{k} = B|$). Thus,
  we only train on rollouts from the current policy
- When learning off-policy, we use a fixed dataset $_{k} = $ of $B$ trajectories from another policy $\pi'$.

Indicate which of the statements **I-III** always hold in the following cases.
\begin{align}
1. &\text {N = 1 and...  }&I\qquad &II\qquad &III\\
&a. on-policy in tablular setting. &\Box\qquad &\Box\qquad &\Box \\
&b. off-policy in tabular setting.&\Box\qquad &\Box\qquad &\Box \\
2. &\text { N > 1 and...}\\
&a. on-policy in tablular setting.&\Box\qquad &\Box\qquad &\Box \\
&b. off-policy in tabular setting.&\Box\qquad &\Box\qquad &\Box \\
3. &\text {In the limite as $N\to\infty$ and...}\\
&a. on-policy in tablular setting.&\Box\qquad &\Box\qquad &\Box \\
&b. off-policy in tabular setting.&\Box\qquad &\Box\qquad &\Box \\
\end{align}

## My Understanding

1. When N = 1

- I: $
  Q_{\phi_{k+1}}(s, a)=r(s,a) + \gamma \max_{a}Q_{\phi_{k}}(s_{t+1}, a_{t+1})
  $, which is the Q function of the last policy, so this is the unbiased estimate of last policy?
- II: Because of the contraction of Bellman operator, and the expression of Q is suffcient for Q value function, this is also right?
- III: Statement is also right because of the contraction of Bellman Operator.